# slide-to-captcha submission serverside verification?

Tags: php, form-submit, captcha

I'm using slide-to-captcha ([slie-to-captcha-master](https://github.com/kthornbloom/slide-to-submit)) and wanted to know how to verify that the Form was submitted using "slide-to-captcha" (PHP)?

"*NOTE* This is a demo for the slider component. By its self, it doesn't prevent spam because bots can submit forms on their own. This needs extended so that there's a check to see if the form was submitted using the dragged element, or by another method."

I understand how to check for POST etc and button submissions, but at a loss to see how to verify for the DIV?

Comment: From looking at the code it provides no server side protection and can be easily defeated.  It only gets in the way of real users, not bots that will just submit data to your form action and bypass and client side checks or validation.